# How should the physics be on an halfpipe like in a skate game in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rotation, movement

I am making a inline skating game. My player is skating based on the normals of the surface of the ground. But when I skate up a halfpipe it flies in the Air but doesnt comes down like it should be, it changes position in the Air and my player falls horizontally on the ground I cant get up anymore like this when he is lying on the Ground. I want it to be physically jump up and come down again the player should align on the ramp again not just fly in the air and drop down on the ground? What infos should you need to answer this question properly I will edit the question then?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should add an animated gif or a link to a youtube video to show your issue.

Comment: Sorry to say it but this question is too broad and opinionated to answer (look at our help center at the top for more details about this site). Also, in my opinion, the physics should just be however you feel they should be, unless your looking for realism, then that would make a good question to ask.

Comment: I added two Photos to the question this should make it a bit clearer what goes wrong with the physics.

Comment: This does not seem that broad _or_ opinionated to me at all. It's pretty interesting.

Comment: Well everyone has its other view thats why I asking this question here maybe some know more about it maybe some not haha

Comment: In the image it looks like the skater goes up and comes back down, but has moved across a little distance. Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, but I guess it could be my jump function. My Player jumps up with velocity in the Y-direction but I dont know how I could change that I will still jump to Y-Direction when im on ground but not when Im on a halfpipe.

Comment: @Daniel are you asking how to make the character's jump impulse point perpendicular to the surface? If not, can you try editing your question to describe in more detail what's happening now, and contrast it against what you want to happen instead?

Comment: I found out that my problem could be caused from my jump function thats why I made a new Question.